# Combine MASQUERADING and NETMAP in iptables POSTROUTING

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, masquerade

We have some clients (networks) which are connected via VPN to our server network.
Let's say client has e.g. `192.168.0.1/32` and our server network is on `10.1.0.0/24`.

So the issue now with this client is, that they're already using the `10.1.0.0/24` themselvs, so we cannot have our range on the clients side. Please note, that configuring the clients network is not in our hand.

To avoid issues, we decided to map our network with the following `iptables` rule

```
NETMAP     all  --  any    any     10.1.0.0/24        192.168.0.1          to:192.168.101.0/24
```

for simplicity i skip the other direction aswell as the swanctl configuration details, but connection works both ways.

So far everything is fine for us in this setup.

Now on top of that we have another network, lets says `192.168.1.0/24` which needs to have access to this client and all other sites available from `10.1.0.0/24` - but not the other way round.

So to avoid adding the route everywhere on all the VPNs and servers, we use

```
MASQUERADE  all  --  any    ens18   192.168.1.0/24      anywhere
```

to replace the source IPs.

Both rules are on the VPN Gateway, the `MASQUERADE` rule comes first.

So as far as i understand, the `MASQUERADE` rule in my setup on the `POSTROUTING` chain is terminating and is the only rule which will be applied during `POSTROUTING` from incoming packages from `192.168.1.0/24`.
Is that correct?

This would mean, that there is no way to have my packages `MASQUERADING` and `NETMAP` 'ed in one step?
Does anyone have an alternative approach for this issue?

Comment: IIRC messy address conflicts were mostly sorted in 1998. Any good reason to not just use the unwanted complexity as an excuse to entirely discontinue cross-network IPv4 traffic?

Comment: From the description I do not immediately see how the nat PREROUTING and POSTROUTING chains (thats two) are too few to apply both source and destination address translation (also two). Which routing, encapsulation or translation step is causing the trouble?

Comment: @anx to sum up, i need two `SNAT` rules if you want to put it that way. First i need to have `192.168.1.0/24` to `10.1.0.0/24` (MASQUERADING uses the VPN /32 here) and  `10.1.0.0/24` to `192.168.101.0/24`.